# Storyboard vs XIB

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I pretty much a rookie in XCODE and almost all of the tuts availible are explaining programming with XIB file with file's owner etc.. The newest version of XCODE only works with Storyboards, and I couldn't find anything which would help. So please, someone have to got a good tutorial I think. It would really help me out. Thanks

Sjors

Comment: There are lots of storyboard tutorials out there as well. One for example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 2):

when you create a project (File -> New -> Project -> select a template ex Single View..) remove the tag to "use storyboard" then you will get a xib file instead of a storyboard... now you can follow tutorials that use xib files :)

tip: if you follow old tutorials...allot of the time you also have to remove use automatic reference Counting because before Xcode 4 they all used manual method ( release etc)

Good luck!